# How to do road segmentation in SQL?

Tags: while-loop, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012
I have a list of roads, each one has some length. For example like this:

```
Road  Length   
A         18
B         40
C         65
```

I want to divide these roads into 20 km sections. so the result table looks like this:

```
Road  From   To
A        0   18
B        0   20
B       20   40
C        0   20
C       20   40
C       40   60
C       60   65
```

I guess I have to use while loop, but I don`t know how to construct the syntax.
Only I was able to do with my sql skills is code like this:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE 
(
  Road VARCHAR(10)
  ,RoadLength INT
)
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES ('A', 18)
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES ('B', 40)
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES ('C', 65)
;
DECLARE @t2 TABLE 
(
  Road VARCHAR(10)
  ,SectionFrom INT
  ,SectionTo INT
)
;
DECLARE @max AS INT
        ,@a AS INT
SET @max = (SELECT MAX(RoadLength) FROM @t1);
SET @a = 0;

 WHILE @a <= @max
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @t2 
     SELECT Road
            ,@a
            ,@a + 20 
     FROM @t1
   SET @a = @a + 20
 END
;
DELETE a
FROM @t2 a
join @t1 b ON a.Road = b.Road
WHERE a.SectionFrom >= b.RoadLength
;
UPDATE a SET SectionTo = b.RoadLength
FROM @t2 a
JOIN @t1 b ON a.Road = b.Road
WHERE a.SectionTo > b.RoadLength 
;
SELECT *
FROM @t2
ORDER BY Road, SectionFrom
```

So for each road a insert number of sections for the longest road, then I delete those extra sections and update last section, which are shorter then 20 km.
Result is satisfying, but of course, the code is awful and very slow on higher volume of data.

Any suggestions how to do this smarter way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A calendar table really comes in handy here.  We can define a table (or a CTE) which contains all the segments which we want to appear in the report.  That is, each row of this "calendar" table will contain a start and a finish distance, beginning with 0 to 20, then 20 to 40, and onwards.

Then, all we need do do is join this calendar table to your table of roads:

```
WITH roads AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS Road, 18 AS Length UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 40 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 65
),
sections AS (
    SELECT 0 AS start, 20 AS finish UNION ALL
    SELECT 20, 40 UNION ALL
    SELECT 40, 60 UNION ALL
    SELECT 60, 80 UNION ALL
    SELECT 80, 100
)

SELECT
    r.Road,
    s.start,
    CASE WHEN r.Length < s.finish THEN r.Length ELSE s.finish END AS finish
FROM sections s
INNER JOIN roads r
    ON s.start < r.Length;
```

[image]

### Demo

One comment to make on the above query is that we use a `CASE` expression to decide what to report as the finish distance.  This is because the final segment of each road might not be completely coincident with the multiple-of-20 boundary we are using for segments.  So, we always report the *smaller* of the road length or the end of the segment.

Comment: Thanks Tim, helped a lot:)